# Creating a few controls in code behind failing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I want to add or remove a few controls to a `StackPanel` when a certain radio button is checked.

I suspect setting the foreground binding of the `Slider` control is wrong.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel Name ="Upgrades" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
     <RadioButton Name="rb1" Content="Upgrade rb1" />
     <RadioButton Name="rb2" Content="Upgrade rb2" />
     <RadioButton Name="rb3" Content="Upgrade rb3" />
     <RadioButton Name="rb4" Content="Upgrade rb4" IsChecked="True"/>
     <RadioButton Name="AllFour" Content="All Four" Checked="AllFour_Checked" Unchecked="AllFour_Unchecked" />       
     <Button Name="StartUpgrades" Margin="0 0 0 0" Click="StartUpgrades_Click" >Start</Button>
</StackPanel>

<!-- I want to add these controls to the stackpanel before the StartUpgrades Button Control
<Label Name="SelectThreads" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Select Threads</Label>
<Slider  Name="SliderThreadAmount" Minimum="1" Maximum="4" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Style="{DynamicResource SliderStyle}" Foreground="{DynamicResource SliderSelectionRangeBackgroundBrush}" IsVisibleChanged="SliderThreadAmount_IsVisibleChanged"></Slider>
<Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="SliderThreadValue" BorderBrush="Gray" Content="{Binding ElementName=SliderThreadAmount,Path=Value}"></Label> -->
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void AllFour_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Label label1 = new Label();
    label1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

    Slider sl = new Slider();
    sl.Minimum = 1;
    sl.Maximum = 4;
    sl.TickFrequency = 1;
    sl.IsSnapToTickEnabled = true;
    sl.SetResourceReference(Control.StyleProperty, "SliderStyle");
    sl.Foreground.SetValue(Control.StyleProperty, "SliderSelectionRangeBackgroundBrush");

    Label label2 = new Label();
    label2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    label2.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    label2.Content = "{Binding ElementName=sl,Path=Value}";

    Upgrades.Children.Add(label1);
    Upgrades.Children.Add(sl);
    Upgrades.Children.Add(label2);
}

private void AllFour_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Upgrades.Children.Remove(label1);
    Upgrades.Children.Remove(sl);
    Upgrades.Children.Remove(label2);
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong? You say what you want, but not the results of what you've tried.

Comment: I get this message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Comment: Please refer to my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set the `Foreground` property of the `Slider`:

```
sl.SetResourceReference(Slider.ForegroundProperty, "SliderSelectionRangeBackgroundBrush");
```

And this to bind the `Content` property of the `Label` to the `Value` property of the `Slider`:

```
label2.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("Value") { Source = sl });
```

> I get this message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Use the dispatcher to remove add the controls. Here is a full example that works:

```
Slider sl;
Label label1;
Label label2;
private void AllFour_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label1 = new Label();
    label1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

    sl = new Slider();
    sl.Minimum = 1;
    sl.Maximum = 4;
    sl.TickFrequency = 1;
    sl.IsSnapToTickEnabled = true;
    sl.SetResourceReference(Control.StyleProperty, "SliderStyle");
    sl.SetResourceReference(Slider.ForegroundProperty, "SliderSelectionRangeBackgroundBrush");

    label2 = new Label();
    label2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    label2.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    label2.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("Value") { Source = sl });

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        Upgrades.Children.Add(label1);
        Upgrades.Children.Add(sl);
        Upgrades.Children.Add(label2);
    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
}

private void AllFour_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Upgrades.Children.Remove(label1);
    Upgrades.Children.Remove(sl);
    Upgrades.Children.Remove(label2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically add the radio buttons you can use an `ItemsControl` bound to a collection

```
<StackPanel Name ="Upgrades" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UpgradeButtons}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Content="{Binding UpgradeName}" IsChecked="{Binding UpgradeChecked}" />
               </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
     <RadioButton Name="AllFour" Content="All Four" IsChecked="{Binding AllFourSelected}" />       
     <Button Name="StartUpgrades" Margin="0 0 0 0" Command="{Binding StartUpgrades}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This does assume moving towards a MVVM style, with a `MainViewModel` and each upgrade would be a `UpgradeViewModel`.